# Reset writeHTML() buffer in mPDF

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

Is it possible to clear `writeHTML()` buffer in mPDF? I want to check page count and re-generate PDF until page count is OK.

Comment: Does https://mpdf.github.io/paging/page-numbering.html help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest and most foolproof solution will be creating a clean `Mpdf\Mpdf` instance.